# Property or indexer must have at least one accessor

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#, trying to get to grips with accessors at the moment.
I'm going nuts looking at this, I have no idea what I've done wrong:

```
class BankAccount
{
    // *PROPERTIES* 
    private int _initialDeposit = 0;

    // **ACCESSORS** 
    public int SavingsAccount
    {
        set
        {
            _initialDeposit = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _initialDeposit;
        }
    }
}
```

The Form looks like this:

```
public partial class BankForm : Form
{
    private BankAccount _myAccount;

    public BankForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myAccount = new BankAccount();
    }

    private void initialDepositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myAccount.SavingsAccount = Convert.ToInt32(initialDepositTextBox.Text);
        bankAccountListBox.Text = "Account opened with initial Deposit " + initialDepositTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Property or indexer must have at least one accessor

Comment: What is the issue you are running into?

Comment: Where does the error appear?

Comment: An error appears in the Error list. "'BankForm.BankAccount.InitialDeposit': property or indexer must have at least one accessor"

Comment: Some constructive feedback: What you've comment labelled as a property is a field, and what you have labelled as accessors is a property. Also its conventional to have get appear before set.

Comment: According to your error, you are trying to access the property named `InitialDeposit`. There is no property with that name: you named it `SavingsAccount`. But you are not showing any code where that happens.

Comment: Are you sure you've posted all the relevant code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had a longer program written which would not compile, but have been slowly stripping it back to see where the problem was. This is as basic as I can get, but I still can't compile it.

Comment: Well, did you include the line on which the compiler barfs? I can't see it...

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was strange, I can't find 'InitialDaposit' anywhere. Will double-check now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Whereever you are trying to access `BankAccount.InitialDeposit` , you should use `BankAccount.SavingsAccount`. Also, your BankForm is partial class. Check for designer file

Comment: It sounds like you have a line like `public int InitialDeposit {}` in `BankAccount` somewhere.

Comment: OK, it seems to have cleared itself, I was searching for the 'InitialDeposit' reference and couldn't find it. I am using a Remote Desktop Connection, so I turned it off and on again. No more error. No idea why.

Comment: Side notes: 1- You should not give a property a totally different name than its backing field. 2- It looks like you can use an auto-implemented property in this case. 3- We usually write the get before the set.

Comment: Thanks for the help, glad the problem wasn't with my code, but annoyed the remote connection meant the errors were preventing me from compiling after they'd been fixed. I shall re-label the class and put get before set in future. Amen.

Comment: I have added the error in the question body (from the title)

Comment: I was getting this error since I was defining the property having in mind the $"{{ get; set; }} instead of the simple "{ get; set;}".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not getting any errors.  Move location of private BankAccount _myAccount;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BankForm
{

    public partial class BankForm : Form
    {
        public BankForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _myAccount = new BankAccount();
        }
        private BankAccount _myAccount;

        private void initialDepositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _myAccount.SavingsAccount = Convert.ToInt32(initialDepositTextBox.Text);
            bankAccountListBox.Text = "Account opened with initial Deposit " + initialDepositTextBox.Text;
        }

    }
    class BankAccount
    {
        // *PROPERTIES* 
        private int _initialDeposit = 0;

        // **ACCESSORS** 
        public int SavingsAccount
        {
            set
            {
                _initialDeposit = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _initialDeposit;
            }
        }
    }

}
​
```